# GPG encryption truncates large files ( ~ 4 Gb )

Tags: encryption, pgp

We currently use GPG to encrypt large text files ( ~ 4 Gb ) and occasionally the encrypted and compressed file will be truncated.  I have tried several different algorithms but cannot pinpoint a culprit. Does GPG have a maximum file size after which it will truncate the file?

Comment: I edited your question to make it more of a specific question and less of an open-ended discussion ("_Any suggestions?_" is very open ended). If my edit is not what you are going for, I suggest you edit the question and make it more specific. Also, we'll probably need to move your question to another site, as we don't really deal with tool specifics on this site. I want to get the question in a better state, however, before I migrate it.

Comment: Please also add the GPG version, operating system and the file system used. FAT e.g. has a 4GB limit.

Comment: What cipher are you using? The [GPG FAQ](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html) has a number of entries for ciphers saying, in effect, do not try to use this cipher for a file larger than 4Gb.